# Omit GMT from a NSDate

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, nsdate

I am getting the current time using these code.

```
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [moviePlayer currentPlaybackTime];
NSDate *currentTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
```

Using a date formatter I print this. It prints the following.

1970-01-01 05:30:12 +0530

However the time is printed as 05:30 because of the time zone I think. Acutall I need this to be 00:00. How to format my date like that. It has to be 1970-01-01 00:00:12 +000.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the date formatter's time zone to GMT:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
```